# Android FacebookSDK projects library reference

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used facebook sdk in my android project, everything goes fine, with a library reference of facebook sdk in workspace... but when i have to test it on my real device i don't have a library in the device because it was referenced from my workspace on the system,

I have tried putting facebookSdk.jar in my libs folder and had reference from there too but there comes following exceptions:

> 08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$layout
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   08-21 17:17:27.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2976):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

any solutions?

Comment: eclipse ADT
Build: v22.0.5-757759

Comment: You need to specify the sdk as a library and set dependencies, I can show you screenshots if needed

Comment: yes i had sepecified it as a library, but the problem is to export it to my real device, if your solutions handles that kindly show me the screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution helped me. Check this please:

[image: specify the sdk as a library]

[image: set dependencies]